# Get exit code of a bash command executed using $()

Tags: bash

I have a bash command that runs a script which is used to upload a local file to a remote repository and return the URL of the file. To run the script I use $(). The issue is I would like to get the exit code of the command executed in bash.
I tried this approach but it doesn't work:

```
my_exit_code=0
URL_FILE=$(./upload-file.sh -f ${file} -r ${region}); my_exit_code=$?
echo "my_exit_code is $my_exit_code"
echo "URL_FILE is $URL_FILE"
```

Any help to know how to get the right my_exit_code?

Comment: That is exactly how you do it. What makes you think it "doesn't work"?

Comment: Oh, okay. I believed it was wrong... there must be some other problem then. Thank you!

Comment: @glennjackman the fact is that the command running inside $() return `ENOENT: no such file or directory` because it actually executes a node script which I can't modify. This error doesn;t progress in executing the two echo commands... I mean I can't then see printed anything. Any idea what to do?

Comment: *"doesn;t progress in executing the two echo commands"* .. Look for `set -e` in your script above the `URL_FILE=....` line and comment it out. A super-rare case would be `bash -e ./myScript.....` . Good luck.

Comment: @dventi3, just in case if you are doing something like `local URL_FILE=$(…)`, then try removing `local`. If that's not the case, maybe try your command without `$()` and check if the following `echo`s work?

Comment: Thank you to everyone who answered! It seems @shellter was right! I haven't seen there was set -e

Comment: Protip: Always copy the code from your own post into a new file, run it, and make sure the problem still appears. This is how you know you've included everything that matters.

Comment: Get into the habit of quoting your variables: `-f "$file" -r "$region"` -- braces are not quotes